# Performing an action when user hits "View" from a local notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, notifications, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to perform an action (opening another app with URL scheme e.g) when the user hits the view button from a local notification without opening my app who sent the notification?

*An Example:*
I sent a local notification with the alertText "Check your Website".
The user gets the notification, presses view and Safari opens automatically without my app opening.

I know its possible to check immediately what to do when my app opens and open safari with the URL scheme but i think it´s not so comfortable to do so, because the user sees my app opening every time.

Thanks for your answer in advance and sorry if my question is not understandable immediately (I´m not a native)

Lale

Answer (score 0):

To listen to these types of events you can use one of these functions:

```
// On iOS 4.0+ only, listen for background notification

if(&UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != nil) 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(function) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}

// Register for notification when the app shuts down

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(function) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

// On iOS 4.0+ only, listen for foreground notification

if(&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification != nil) 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(function) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but these events just tell me that I go back in the app, enter the background and so on, don´t they?
They also don´t tell me if I come from a notification or not. What I wanted was a way to bypass this by going directly to another app not to my app first. There is no way to set a function what to do when view i pressed, when you schedule the notification? Lale

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Pressing the "View" button will trigger your app.
Maybe with the new iOS 5 coming soon something will change, download the beta and have a look.